# I am retrieving 4 columns from a database and using simple cursor adapter to attach it to list view

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

This is how I'm handling in my main class

```
myDbHelper=new DataBaseHelper(this);
try {
     myDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
}

try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
}catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}

        populaterows();
}

public void populaterows(){
    Cursor c=myDbHelper.getAllRows();

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                simplecursoradapter(c);

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }


        myDbHelper.close();

}

public void simplecursoradapter(Cursor c){

        String[] listnames=new String[] {"Songname","Composer","Film","Year"};


        int[] toviewids=new int[] {R.id.songtext,R.id.composertext,R.id.film,R.id.director};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapater;

        myCursorAdapater =new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listitems, c, listnames, toviewids);

        ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        listview.setAdapter(myCursorAdapater);

        //this.setListadapter(myCursorAdapater);

     }
```

In my dataBaseHelper class

public Cursor getAllRows()
         {

```
 String Table_name="list";

 Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from "+Table_name, null);



 return c;

     }
```

I am getting an error of this sort
* Terminate instrumentation of the application.  This will cause the
     * application process to exit, removing this instrumentation from the next
     * time the application is started. 
     *
     * @param resultCode Overall success/failure of instrumentation. 
     * @param results Any results to send back to the code that started the 
     *                instrumentation.
     */
    public void finish(int resultCode, Bundle results) {
        if (mAutomaticPerformanceSnapshots) {
            endPerformanceSnapshot();
        }
        if (mPerfMetrics != null) {
            if (results == null) {
                results = new Bundle();
            }
            results.putAll(mPerfMetrics);

Comment: How do I fix this issue of attaching the database rows to various views in a list..Plz help

Comment: Can you paste your stacktrace?

Comment: call `simplecursoradapter()` just once

Comment: Then how do I populate each list view??

Comment: what `"each"`? how many `ListViews` do you have?